# Как точно определять границы контролов WinForms/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

WinForms добавляю picturebox а в него круглую картинку, но при этом контейнер остаётся прямоугольным. Когда на picturebox вешаю onClick, то появляются пустые области в которых метод срабатывает, но картинки там нет.
С маленькими картинками это не критично, но с большими появляются сложности.
Если картинка будет иметь более сложную форму, например звезды, можно ли решить аналогичный вопрос?
Какие способы обхода данной проблемы существуют в WinForms и WPF?

Comment: Ну вы уж определитесь WPF или WinForms, решения принципиально разные будут

Comment: Разнесите вопросы. WinForms и WPF отличаются чуть больше чем полностью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотели извращений? Пожалуйста. Решение для WinForms, как такое сделать в WPF пока не разбирался, это из архивов когда еще кодил ради кода =)

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();//базовая инициализация формы
        var customPanel = new Panel();
        ////Подписываемся на событие Click, для проверки зон активности контрола
        customPanel.Click += CustomPanel_Click;
        //маленький хак для получения видимого размера напечатанного текста 
        var strSize = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1)).MeasureString("ХОЙ!", new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 100, FontStyle.Bold)).ToSize();
        //Задаем форму контрола
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddString("ХОЙ!", FontFamily.GenericMonospace, (int)FontStyle.Bold, 100, new Point(0, 0), StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        customPanel.Region = new Region(gp);
        customPanel.Size = strSize;
        customPanel.BackColor = Color.Black;
        //Добавляем контрол на форму
        Controls.Add(customPanel);
    }

    private void CustomPanel_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Попал!");
    }
}
```

Надеюсь это достаточно сложная форма контрола =)

Только предупреждаю сразу, забудьте про стандартные стили оформления бордеров и т.д. и т.п. Все они рассчитаны на стандартную прямоугольную форму. Как только вы взялись за изменение формы контрола, готовьтесь рисовать все, от рамочек выделения, до теней, ну и контент само собой. В остальном контролы с произвольной формой ни чем не отличаются от обычных.