# C#. Как в Windows Form изображение сделать круглым

Tags: c#

Создавая программу, мне понадобилось создать picture Box, который для моего дизайна должен быть круглым. Помогите понять, как это сделать. Если есть возможность, киньте пример в ответы.

Comment: Если вы хотите делать интерфйсы с красивым дизайном, то лучше импользуйте WPF для этого

Comment: @tym32167: это да, но на WF в создании круглого элемента нет ничего сверхъестественного, так что вопрос заслуживает право на существование)

Comment: Так вам изображение нужно сделать круглым или PictureBox? Это разные вещи.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: я так понял, что товарищу нужен именно круглый PictureBox

Comment: [Control.Region](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.region?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.Region);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Ну и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/751877/198316) еще пример необычной формы контрола. Дубль или нет, смотрите сами, я бы закрыл как дубль, хоть в ответе и не совсем та форма, которую просили.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как точно определять границы контролов WinForms/WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/750561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-winforms-wpf)