# C# Клик через окно, но не через елементы

Tags: c#, winforms

C# winforms, нужно сделать чтобы форма пропускала клики, а елементы на ней - нет. Ниже код делает так что всё пропускает клики. Есть какое-то решение?

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
        const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
        const int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
        const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            var style = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
            SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, style | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
        }
```

Comment: Самое простейшее и лучшее решение - взять WPF и писать на нем...

Comment: Прозрачность и Winforms - несовместимы.

Comment: Тогда встречный вопрос, куда копать если на WPF писать, до этого кидали решения, но они либо не рабочие, либо елементы тоже не кликабельны

Comment: А сама форма должна быть видна или можно убрать весь этот лишний фон и оставить только элементы формы? Если да, то посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/487760/198316) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/751877/198316)